# Why isn't the size of union the size of the largest member?

Tags: c++, c, unions

```
union data {
    double number2;
    char name[20];
};

int main() {

  printf("%i\n", sizeof(union data));

  return 0;
}
```

I expected it to be 20 because it is the largest, but the result is 24.

Answer (score 12):

Besides the size of the largest member, the union must also consider the alignment of the member with the strictest alignment requirements. `double` must be aligned on 8-byte boundary, so the union must have size that's a multiple of 8. Otherwise in an array of `data`, some instances of `number2` would be misaligned.

Comment: There can also be other ABI requirements, e.g. in ARM OABI with gcc, `struct s { char x[2]; }` has size 4.